# Trouble with interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I am dealing with two interfaces:

```
public interface ICoordinates
{
    double Latitude { get; set; }
    double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public interface ILocation
{
    ICoordinates Coordinate1 { get; set; }
    ICoordinates Coordinate2 { get; set; }
}
```

Implementing them so:

```
class Coordinates : ICoordinates
{
    public double Latitude {get; set;}
    public double Longitude {get; set;}

    public Coordinates(double p1, double p2)
    {
        this.Latitude = p1;
        this.Longitude = p2;
    }
}
class Location : ILocation
{
    public Coordinates Coordinate1 { get; set; }
    public Coordinates Coordinate2 { get; set; }

    public Location(Coordinates c1, Coordinates c2)
    {
        this.Coordinate1 = c1;
        this.Coordinate2 = c2;
    }
}
```

However this gives me a compiler error.

```
1>C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Twitter_twitinvi\Twitter_twitinvi\Program.cs(36,11,36,19): error CS0738: 'Twitter_twitinvi.Location' does not implement interface member 'Tweetinvi.Core.Interfaces.Models.ILocation.Coordinate2'. 'Twitter_twitinvi.Location.Coordinate2' cannot implement 'Tweetinvi.Core.Interfaces.Models.ILocation.Coordinate2' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Tweetinvi.Core.Interfaces.Models.ICoordinates'.
```

Can't understand what I m doing wrong here. As class Coordinates does inherit from ICoordinates. So what does this error mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your location class you need to use properties of type `ICoordinates`, not `Coordinates`:

```
class Location : ILocation
{
    public ICoordinates Coordinate1 { get; set; }
    public ICoordinates Coordinate2 { get; set; }

    public Location(ICoordinates c1, ICoordinates c2)
    {
        this.Coordinate1 = c1;
        this.Coordinate2 = c2;
    }
}
```

When you have an interface you need to implement it just as it is, including return types. Even though class `Coordinates` implements `ICoordinates` you still need to use exact signature, you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

You already got [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29863985/240733) explaining that the signatures of the `Coordinates1` and `Coordinates2` properties in your implementing class (`Location`) must exactly match the signatures as they are defined in the interface `ILocation`.

You might ask why that is so. Let's consider that someone other than you might create an alternate implementation of the `ICoordinates` interface:

```
class Coordinates : ICoordinates { /* your implementation */ }

class FooCoordinates : ICoordinates { /* an alternative implementation */ }
```

Now, let's say we have a reference to an `ILocation` object. As per the interface definition, we can set the `Coordinates1` and `Coordinates2` properties to *any* object that implements `ICoordinates`. That is, the following would work:

```
ILocation location = …;
location.Coordinates1 = new Coordinates();
location.Coordinates2 = new FooCoordinates();
```

Now let's consider your implementation of `ILocation`. You want to declare your properties to have the type `Coordinates` instead of `ICoordinates` (as the interface mandates). If the resulting properties were a legal implementation for `ILocation.Coordinates[1|2]`, then the following would be possible:

```
Location location = new Location();
ILocation locationAsSeenThroughTheInterface = location;
locationAsSeenThroughTheInterface.Coordinates2 = new FooCoordinates();
Coordinates coordinates2 = location.Coordinates2;
```

That is, you could set `Coordinates2` to a `FooCoordinates` object by first casting `location` to the interface type that it supports; then you would read the same property back directly through `location` (without a cast). According to the declared types, you'd expect to get back a `Coordinates` object when the property was set to a `FooCoordinates` object.

Or, in different words: The last two lines of code are problematic. The penultimate line of code would set a property of type `Coordinates` to a `FooCoordinates` object, which should of course be forbidden... but the type system would have no way of knowing. The last line of code would read a `FooCoordinates` object out of a `Coordinates`-types property, which should be equally impossible.

There is only one way to prevent these ugly type mismatches: You are required to implement the interface exactly as you've defined it; including the precise return types.

Comment: Yes I understand now. I think my initial confusion was regarding interfaces being able to be instantiated. Now I understand that they can, furthermore, if I am correct, your explanation implies that the interface will enforce only the necessary properties to be contained (ignoring the possible others in case of instantiation with an alternate implementation, such as FooCoordinates)